# On MS Access, group by then filter

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a table on ms access which has 13 columns.I want to `group by` column `Name` then check the latest one by comparing column `id` and take the record if the latest row has value if not take the previous record. the comparison will be done for each columns.

```
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| id  |Name |colum1 |colum2 |colum3 |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 1   |a    |x      |       |x      |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 2   |b    |       |y      |y      |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 3   |a    |z      |z      |       |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 4   |a    |m      |       |       |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Expected output

```
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| id  |Name |colum1 |colum2 |colum3 |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 2   |b    |       |y      |y      |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| 4   |a    |m      |z      |x      |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: You said "MS Access", but you tagged "MySQL". Which is it?

Comment: It is better to share what you have done so far with sql

Comment: It is ms Access, I tried to tag as access but it consider it as new tag. But in any case if i got the idea even on any sql format , transferring it to ms access will not be that much difficult  i guess .

Comment: @ozy so far i tried self join as _subin_ suggested.

Comment: I don't agree. MS Access's SQL dialect is rather limited. It's better to get an answer tailored for MS Access

Comment: @LukasEder i agree, it would be grate if i got an answer on ms Access. But if not.. at least on any sql also will help me to get the idea.  cause i can't come up with any work around to do this.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do Self Join.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM
    table_name T1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT `Name`,MAX(`id`) AS ID FROM table_name GROUP BY `Name` ) T2 
 ON T1.`id`= T2.`ID` AND T1.`Name` = T2.`Name`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works to get the latest record by id. but i want also to check each columns, and if the column is empty or null it has to take from the next latest row. On the table above column 2 and 3 are empty for the id row 4, so it takes value z form row 3 and value x from row 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work in MS Access. It works in SQL Server. Even if it does, it will be very slow.

```
SELECT
    Groups.Name
    ,(
        SELECT TOP(1) T.colum1
        FROM T
        WHERE T.Name = Groups.Name AND T.colum1 <> ''
        ORDER BY T.ID DESC
    ) AS C1
    ,(
        SELECT TOP(1) T.colum2
        FROM T
        WHERE T.Name = Groups.Name AND T.colum2 <> ''
        ORDER BY T.ID DESC
    ) AS C2
    ,(
        SELECT TOP(1) T.colum3
        FROM T
        WHERE T.Name = Groups.Name AND T.colum3 <> ''
        ORDER BY T.ID DESC
    ) AS C3
FROM
    (
        SELECT Name
        FROM T
        GROUP BY Name
    ) AS Groups
```